# How to get VBA (word) to find the first occurence of a specific field-text on each page?

Tags: vba, ms-word, find

I'm setting up a new word VBA tool to create lists of hyperlinks for documents using reference manager 12. The document includes references, and I need to highlight all references the first time they appear on a page. Therefore, first I need the VBA macro to mark all wbFieldAddin (value 81) the first time they occur on each page. So to be clear, it should not be restricted to mark the first field on each page, it should be restricted to mark the first unique field (based on the text/reference) on each page.

I have created a code to find all the field codes and highlight them (see below) which works. I have not been able to alter the search to only include the first unique reference on each page.

Example of desired output (bold=highlight):
[Page 1] *This is an example **(Author1 et al. 2019)**. This is the next part of the example **(Author2 et al. 2018)**. This is the last part of the example (Author1 et al. 2019).*

```
Sub ShowFieldsInDoc()

Dim objField As Field
Dim objDoc As Document
Dim strCodeText As String

Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

With objDoc
  For Each objField In .Fields
    If objField.Type = wdFieldAddin Then
      objField.Select
      Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    End If

  Next objField
End With

End Sub
```

The macro finds all wdFieldAddin, but I need it to be limited to only the first unique reference on each page.

Thank you so much in advance, and please let me know if I need to elaborate on anything else. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the page number of each "hit" and comparing it to the previous "hit" should work. The `Information` property of the `Selection` and `Range` objects can provide it using the `wdActiveEndPageNumber` argument.

```
Sub ShowFieldsInDoc()

    Dim objField As Field
    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim strCodeText As String
    Dim pg As Long, pgLast As Long

    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    pg = 0

    With objDoc
      For Each objField In .Fields
        If objField.Type = wdFieldAddin Then
          objField.Select
          pgLast = pg
          pg = objField.result.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
          'OR
          'pg = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
          If pg <> pgLast Then
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
          End If
        End If

      Next objField
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you very much for the quick response. It is much appreciated. It runs, but it only highlight the first reference (wdFieldAddin) on each page. Let me elaborate a bit; what I envisioned was that it would highlight all unique references at the first occurence on each page. So if author1 is mentioned 2-3 times on a page it will only highlight the first occurence on the page. However, if author2 is also mentioned on the page, it should highlight this field as well. Also if author3 is mentioned 2 times, it will also highlight the first occurence of this. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I answsered the question, as it stands @AndersPoppThyme. If you need something else, then that should have been stated *in the question*. Don't change the rules after-the-fact. You should post a new question with *all relevant* information. In this case, including where this list of references should be coming from and how each should be "searched".

Comment: Well, Idid write “So to be clear, it should not be restricted to mark the first field on each page, it should be restricted to mark the first unique field (based on the text/reference) on each page.” - and I added an example to help. I really tried to be as specific as possible. This is not a new question. However, I can try and create the post again with more details if that is what is best?